# What to put in rspec's expect for a globally available object?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a custom matcher for my logging output, mostly so that I can customize the error output to be more readable and helpful.

The thing being examined for the test is the array returned by `LoggingSpecHelper.log_events`, a module class method (i.e. not a module instance method). Therefore, it is available without the need for it to be passed as a parameter.

`LoggingSpecHelper.log_events` is kind of long to specify in each expectation, and anyway I'd prefer to hide that implementation detail from the caller, in case that implementation changes. That leads to my using `expect(:logging)`, where `:logging` is a dummy value which has no meaning and is not examined. This, however, is awkward and confusing, leaving the reader scratching their head thinking "he's examining a *symbol*?"

Here is an example of how it is currently called; in this case I'm looking to see if a fatal error occurs in the log that contains 'something is misconfigured' (not a real production message):

```rb
expect(:logging).to have_log_output_match(:fatal, 'something is misconfigured')
```

The long form of this, and what is happening in the matcher, is below, but if I do this instead of calling the matcher, I don't get to see what *is* in the log if an error occurs (the matcher includes log content in the failure message):

```rb
expect(LoggingSpecHelper.log_events.count do |event|
  event.level == :fatal && /something is misconfigured/.match?(event.message)
end).to be == 1
```

How would you suggest I handle this? I don't think shared examples are what I want here because this log expectation might not be the only expectation in the example.

As an aside, I should probably rename the matcher so that it is clear that I am testing for 1 and not >=1 occurrences.

Comment: [See Here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-12/docs/configuration/custom-settings) for details on "Custom Settings" which might be useful. I am not sure I understand entirely what you are trying to do here and any code examples you can provide might be enlightening.

Comment: sounds a bit like you would want to use rspecs shared examples, but it's hard to tell without concrete code examples https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I've added to the question to address your points. Please let me know if I can be more helpful.

Comment: Not sure I see a problem here. If `log_events` is public - just test it. In this case you will be testing a public interface of a module, and this is perfectly reasonable. If it is _not_ part of a public interface - don't test it at all (in this case you _are_ testing an implementation, that is not that good idea in general)

Comment: Are you testing this everywhere or in isolation? Seems like you could go with `expect(LoggingSpecHelper).to have_log_event(:fatal,'something is misconfigured')` and then custom matcher on that where "actual" is simply the Logger.

Comment: @engineersmnky I see that using the module name might be less confusing; at least it would point the reader to the implementation of the matcher. However, from a parameter point of view it would be redundant because it would not (need to) be used in the test itself, right?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Testing the log_events directly requires a lot more knowledge of the logging system than I want the test code to need to have. I just need to know if the message appears in the application's log at the expected level. In addition to simpler code in the test, this would enable changing the implementation of the log or log lookup without changing the tests. Is there a reason I should require this lower level knowledge in spite of these points?

Comment: @engineersmnky I did not see anything in the custom settings that seemed helpful in this situation. After seeing the detail I added to the question, do you still think custom settings would be helpful?

Comment: @KeithBennett no custom settings is not useful in this case; however to your other point using the module name is not redundant in any fashion. You are setting an expectation. This should be done on a given object, whether that be the Module in this case or any Class or instance of a class. IMO this would be the correct way to structure such a test. That being said I would also say that you should not need these tests throughout any code base, you shpuld simply test that the Module works as intended (in isolation)...

Comment: ...and then *maybe* test that it gets called with the appropriate parameters at the appropriate times (but even this I would likely stub). If you know the Module works via unit testing then you know it will work in the wild so testing that it works after knowing it works is superfluous.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concepts of what to test and what not to test, for example to test that the LoggingSpecHelper works, but use mocks or stubs to just see that the correct methods are called for the log output calls themselves.

However, there have been so many times when I was testing logging, and encountered a failure, and thought it would be extremely helpful to see what _was_ in the log that differed from my expectation. (cont'd)

Comment: That's why I went down this path. I figured that the pragmatic benefit of dumping the log content in the failure message was more important than ideological approach purity in this case. I found that it _was extremely_ helpful being able to see the log output.

Is there a better way to accomplish that? Do you all still think this is a bad idea? If so, do you agree or not that eliminating the log content makes the test less helpful, and, if so, why do you think that is less important than using the more ideologically pure approach?